# Trying to apply a filter on an ng-repeat which was created in a creative way

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i've been working on an Ionic project where i needed to create a "gallery like" screen,
this is essentially a view of rows, and three items in each row

the content is being pulled from a backend, and as such it need to code to dynamically be able to scale as long as more items retrieved from the backend,

the problem i'm facing is that i can't filter the list of items using a simple filter because the way i create the array is --> `data-ng-repeat="i in range(companies.length)"`

`$scope.companies` is essentially an array of objects, each object represents a company

```
[{..}, {..} ...]
```

and here is the HTML simplified as much as i was able to,

```
<div class"row"
     data-ng-repeat="company in companies"
     data-ng-if="$index % 3 === 0">

  <div class="col col-33"
       data-ng-if="$index < companies.length">

       <img ng-src="img/buttons/{{ companies[$index].image }}">

  </div>

  <div class="col col-33"
       data-ng-if="$index < companies.length">

       <img ng-src="img/buttons/{{ companies[$index + 1].image }}">

  </div>

  <div class="col col-33"
       data-ng-if="$index < companies.length">

       <img ng-src="img/buttons/{{ companies[$index + 2].image }}">

  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

are there any ideas of how can i filter the list by object property?
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you just let the repeater go over companies directly instead of an "empty" array the size of companies? As companies gets changed, the repeater would update as well.

Comment: i would do that happily, but then how can i acheive the "gallery" structure as displayed above? the reason i i use the empty array is so i can create these three columns per row structure

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/etGL7WNMeRCovnKZcGza?p=preview)

Comment: Yes! thanks! simply use float: left on each .col ?

Comment: I just put it on the .col class in the style.css actually - if you dont want to add it there as the class comes from ionic, just make your own one and add it.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't have to break your data into multiple groups and iterate through them in this way.  The Ionic framework is responsive, and `<div class="col-33">` will already automatically break on every 3rd item.  The class `row` isn't even required.

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies">
  <div class="col col-33">
       <img ng-src="img/buttons/{{ company.image }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it appears that using this solution alone causes the elements to break each item in its own row, however, adding a css of float: left on each .col solves it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to s-hoff i managed to do that this way

CSS:

```
.col {
    float: left
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies">
  <div class="col col-33">
       <img ng-src="img/buttons/{{ company.image }}">
  </div>
</div>
```